# Sum Case SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    CompanyCode, PaymentStatus, PaymentType, PaySource,
    SUM(CCur(PaymentAmount)), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentStatus='APPROVED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Approved,  
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Detail_Work 
GROUP BY 
    CompanyCode, PaymentType, PaymentStatus, PaySource 
ORDER BY 
    CompanyCode, PaymentType, PaymentStatus, PaySource
```

And I get the following error:

> Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query Expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN
>   PaymentStatus='APPROVED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'

Comment: The PaymentStatus is either approved or rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `case`.  Use `iif()` instead:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, PaymentStatus, PaymentType, PaySource,    
       SUM(CCur(PaymentAmount)),
       SUM(IIF(PaymentStatus = 'APPROVED', 1, 0)) AS Approved,  COUNT(*) 
FROM Detail_Work 
GROUP BY CompanyCode,PaymentType, PaymentStatus, PaySource 
ORDER BY CompanyCode, PaymentType, PaymentStatus, PaySource;
```

However, I'm not sure why you have `PaymentStatus` in the `GROUP BY`.  Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT CompanyCode, PaymentType, PaySource,    
       SUM(CCur(PaymentAmount)),
       SUM(IIF(PaymentStatus = 'APPROVED', 1, 0)) AS Approved,  COUNT(*) 
FROM Detail_Work 
GROUP BY CompanyCode,PaymentType, PaySource 
ORDER BY CompanyCode, PaymentType, PaySource;
```